# Hive table lock info using spark.sql in Spark 2.4.0 throws error

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

Not able to query hive table lock info using below SQL query in Spark 2.4.0 shell.

```
spark.sql("show locks dbName.tableName")
```

Getting below error

```
scala> spark.sql("show locks dbName.tableName")
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException:
Operation not allowed: show locks(line 1, pos 0)

== SQL ==
show locks dbName.tableName
^^^
at 
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParserUtils$.operationNotAllowed(ParserUtils.scala:39)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkSqlAstBuilder$$anonfun$visitFailNativeCommand$1.apply(SparkSqlParser.scala:1001)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkSqlAstBuilder$$anonfun$visitFailNativeCommand$1.apply(SparkSqlParser.scala:992)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParserUtils$.withOrigin(ParserUtils.scala:99)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkSqlAstBuilder.visitFailNativeCommand(SparkSqlParser.scala:992)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkSqlAstBuilder.visitFailNativeCommand(SparkSqlParser.scala:55)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.SqlBaseParser$FailNativeCommandContext.accept(SqlBaseParser.java:723)
  at org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.AbstractParseTreeVisitor.visit(AbstractParseTreeVisitor.java:42)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AstBuilder$$anonfun$visitSingleStatement$1.apply(AstBuilder.scala:71)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AstBuilder$$anonfun$visitSingleStatement$1.apply(AstBuilder.scala:71)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParserUtils$.withOrigin(ParserUtils.scala:99)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AstBuilder.visitSingleStatement(AstBuilder.scala:70)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AbstractSqlParser$$anonfun$parsePlan$1.apply(ParseDriver.scala:69)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AbstractSqlParser$$anonfun$parsePlan$1.apply(ParseDriver.scala:68)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AbstractSqlParser.parse(ParseDriver.scala:97)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkSqlParser.parse(SparkSqlParser.scala:48)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AbstractSqlParser.parsePlan(ParseDriver.scala:68)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:637)
  ... 48 elided
```

But the same query works in Spark 1.6.0 with hiveContext

My use case is to get the lock info about the hive table inside a spark job in Spark 2.4.0

If there is any way that I can get the table lock info in spark job?

Answer (score 0):

See the below Link.
**Locks are not supported by spark 2.4.0**

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.4/sql/catalyst/src/main/antlr4/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/parser/SqlBase.g4#L195

unsupportedHiveNativeCommands
| kw1=SHOW kw2=LOCKS

https://dbdb.io/db/spark-sql
On the above blog also. Concurrency control section says, It doesn't support locks.